# javascript highlight

Tags: javascript

i try to make the div color changed when click or focus on textbox so i do this js function but it change the textbox color not its div

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* This is the CSS class to use when no focus is on the input control */
    .input_text
    {
        border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
        padding:4px;
        font-size:14px;
        color:#000000;
        background-color:#ffffff;
    }
    /* This is the CSS class to use when the control has focus */
    .input_text:focus, input.input_text_focus
    {
        border-color:#646464;
        background-color:#ffffc0;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // creates a function to set the css class name of input controls when they
    // receive or lose focus.
    setAspnetTextFocus = function() {
        // CSS class name to use when no focus is on the input control
        var classBlur = 'input_text';
        // CSS class name to use when the input control has focus
        var classFocus = 'input_text_focus';
        // get all of the input tags on the page
        var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
            inputElements[i].onfocus = function() {
                if (this.className == 'input_text') {
                    this.className += ' ' + classFocus;
                }
            }
            // add the onblur event and set it to remove the on focused CSS class when it loses focus
            inputElements[i].onblur = function() {
                this.className = this.className.replace(new RegExp(' ' + classFocus + '\\b'), '');
            }
        }
    }
    // attach this event on load of the page
    if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent('onload', setAspnetTextFocus);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="input_text" >
<input type="text" id="TextBox1" class="input_text" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To change the text select color you just need CSS. You wont be able to do it with JavaScript except with not so pretty hacks (you'd need to draw a rectangle on top/below the words on select...)

With CSS tho you just need to do (i believe):

```
#TextBox1::selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Safari */
        }
#TextBox1::-moz-selection {
        background: #ffb7b7; /* Firefox */
}
```

Source: http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/

Just a side note tho in case you care, this is NOT W3C validated CSS.

Answer (score 0):

here is a jsfiddle using JQuery that will do what I think you are asking for: http://jsfiddle.net/pthurlow/GG6Te/

here it is in plain vanilla JS: http://jsfiddle.net/FSZZU/

**EDIT** code from jsfiddle:

html

```
<div class="input_text">
  <input type="text" id="TextBox1" class="input_text" />
</div>
```

script

```
document.getElementById('TextBox1').onfocus = function() {
  this.parentNode.className = 'input_text focus_text';
};
document.getElementById('TextBox1').onblur = function() {
  this.parentNode.className = 'input_text';
};
```

Comment: I dont think he's using jQuery tho

Comment: You might consider including the code directly into your answer, *with* the external jsfiddle link.  That way we keep the meat of the answer on SO, with the external link being in-addition-to your answer.  particularly when the code is relatively brief.